# block.io + scan generated QR code

Tags: php, qrcode, block.io

So i created a **block.io** account and playing around with bitcoin address generation, as well QR codes.

My source code for generating a new bitcoin address is that one:

```
include_once("payment/block_io/block_io.php");
...
$block_io_apikey = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";   // bitcoin API key (testnet)
$block_io_version = 2;                      // API version
$block_io_pin = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$block_io = new BlockIo($block_io_apikey, $block_io_pin, $block_io_version);
...
$obj = $block_io->get_new_address();
// $obj->data->address;   // the bitcoin address for paying to (my BTC)
```

My code for generating QR code is that one:

```
$width  = $height = 250;
$error  = "L"; // handle up to 30% data loss, or "L" (7%), "M" (15%), "Q" (25%)
$border = 1;
$btc_address = "1ArmoryXcfq7TnCSuZa9fQjRYwJ4bkRKfv";   
                     // sample, 
                     // from $block_io->get_new_address()->data->address
$btc_amount  = 0.0001;
$url    = urlencode("bitcoin:$btc_address?amount=$btc_amount");
$filename = sprintf("./payment/block_io/qrcodes_cache/block-io-$btc_address.png");
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
   $qr = webpage_grab( array("url"=>"http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs={$width}x{$height}&cht=qr&chld=$error|$border&chl=$url") );
   $imgIn  = imagecreatefromstring($qr);
   $imgOut = imagecreate($width, $height);
   imagecopy($imgOut, $imgIn, 0,0, 0,0, $width,$height);
   imagepng($imgOut, $filename, 9);
   imagedestroy($imgIn);
   imagedestroy($imgOut);
}
echo "<img src=\"$filename\" width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\" alt=\"Scan my QR !\" />";
```

which generates a QR code using the Google API. I end up with a QR code image that a mobile can scan through an app, paying my newly generated bitcoin address.

My questions are:

***1***. How to pay into a particular bitcoin address just generated using the above code, using say, the bitcoin testnet? but without mobile?? Just block.io api code.

***2***. How to scan that QR code (either testnet or real) using a mobile?

***3***. Can i use, say, blockchain.com application to scan bitcoin addresses (and QR codes by Google API) generated by block.io? or apps does matter between sites?

***4***. My tablet has an old Android OS (4.4.2 kitkat) and does not support Blockchain.app. If i am allowed to use another app for my block.io QR scanning needs, which one would be?

Sorry for the boatload of questions, just started up.